# URL Rewrite based on method

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to re route `GET /post` to `127.0.0.1/post` and `POST /post` to `127.0.0.1:3000/post`?

I need to redirect requests based on its method because here we have a rest API.

One thing is that all POST method must go to an internal server running on port 3000. while all get request must be routed to another server.

Can this be done with Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do many things with Apache and .htaccess :)

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
RewriteRule ^/post 127.0.0.1/post

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^/post 127.0.0.1:3000/post
```